# % diff of 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, average

I have 2 tables - countries (id, name, continent) and population_years (id, population, year, country_id). The data goes from 2000-2010 and I'm trying to calculate the percentage diff in average population for each continent across this time period. I'm trying to do it by creating a temporary table which produces an output of:
[image]

But when I try to calculate the % diff (as you can see from my code below), I don't know how to reference the 'avg pop 2000' and 'avg pop 2010' columns in the code as they haven't been assigned a variable that I can reference. In the code, I've used avg_pop_2010 and avg_pop_2000 to reference these columns - obviously this doesn't actually work.

```
WITH avg_pop AS( SELECT countries.continent, 
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN population_years.year = 2000 THEN population_years.population END), 2) as 'avg pop 2000',
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN population_years.year = 2010 THEN population_years.population END), 2) as 'avg pop 2010'
FROM countries 
JOIN population_years 
WHERE population_years.country_id = countries.id
GROUP BY 1)

SELECT countries.continent, ROUND(((avg_pop_2010 - avg_pop_2000)/avg_pop_2000)*100.0, 2) AS '%diff'
FROM avg_pop;
```

Comment: Don't ever use single quotes for identifiers like aliases of columns. In SQlite you can use square brackets or backticks. So set the aliases inside the CTE to `[avg pop 2000]` and `[avg pop 2010]`. Then do the calculation: `ROUND((([avg pop 2010] - [avg pop 2000])/[avg pop 2000])*100.0, 2) AS [%diff]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to repeat the expressions - with a little optimization:

```
select
    c.continent,
    round(avg(case when py.year = 2000 then py.population end), 2) avg_pop_2000,
    round(avg(case when py.year = 2010 then py.population end), 2) avg_pop_2010,
    round(
        100.* avg(case when py.year = 2010 then py.population else - py.population end)
        / avg(case when py.year = 2000 then py.population end),
        2
    ) percent_diff
from countries c
inner join population_years py on py.country_id = c.id
where py.year in (2010, 2020)
group by c.continent
```

Side notes:

- don't use single quotes for identifiers! They stand for literal strings in standard SQL; in general, you should prefer identifiers that do not need to be quoted. If quoting is needed, use standard double quotes (`"`), which SQLite recognizes
- prefiltering the relevant years with a `where` clause makes the query more efficient
- use standard join syntax; the join condition goes to the `on` clause of the join, not to the `where` clause
- rounding, then computing the percent difference is not accurate; compute first, then round
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH avg_pop AS( SELECT countries.continent, 
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN population_years.year = 2000 THEN population_years.population END), 2) as avg_pop_2000,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN population_years.year = 2010 THEN population_years.population END), 2) as avg_pop_2010
    FROM countries 
    JOIN population_years 
    WHERE population_years.country_id = countries.id
    GROUP BY 1)

    SELECT continent, ROUND((( avg_pop_2000 - avg_pop_2010)/avg_pop_2010)*100, 2) AS '%diff'
    FROM avg_pop;
```

Here is a small demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bc669067d03fa5e90a0c9a221ef9b8ce)

When checking on other comments and answer I realized you need to give different aliases without '' and all will work...I have updated my answer and demo.

Comment: I tried this but in the output for '%diff', I'm getting NULL values for all rows. I'm not sure why?